# Rails 4 form select inputs giving "can't be blank" error when they aren't blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and I have two `select` inputs in my signup form.  When I make a selection and fill out the rest of the form, I get two errors associated with these inputs that say they cannot be blank.  I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors if they aren't blank...

Here are the gems that I'm using that are relevant:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'twitter_cldr'
```

Here is the partial with the fields I'm using:

**app/views/users/_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= f.text_field :name, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'name' %>
<%= f.text_field :email, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'email' %>
<%= f.select :language1, TwitterCldr::Shared::Languages.all.values %>
<%= f.select :language2, TwitterCldr::Shared::Languages.all.values %>
<%= f.password_field :password, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'password' %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'confirm password' %>
```

The columns of the users table is defined as such:

**db/schema.rb**

```
...
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
...
    t.string "language1"
    t.string "language2"
...
end
```

and here is the validation in my user model:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
validates :language1, presence: true
validates :language2, presence: true
```

### My thoughts:

What I'm thinking is that what is being selected in the dropdown is maybe not a string?
That or I have seen that in some cases you have to specify the object that the form is for in the select method like this:

```
<%= f.select :user, :language1, TwitterCldr::Shared::Languages.all.values %>
```

but my problem with this approach is that these fields are in a partial and the object is passed in as a local, so when I do this:

```
<%= f.select f.object, :language1, TwitterCldr::Shared::Languages.all.values %>
```

I get an error about an undefined method 'to_sym' for my class of `User`

Anybody have any suggestions??? Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your development log or add a debug statement to see what the value of `params[:language1]` and `params[:language2]` are once they reach your controller after submitting the form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is most likely a controller error. Make sure that strong params is accepting the attributes:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :language1, :language2)
```

[Look at strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

Comment: also, can you fix your link for me as well as others who want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues as well. Initially, I naively put

def create

```
@micropost = user.microposts.create(params[:microposts])
```

And when I put

```
 @micropost = user.microposts.create(micropost_params), 

private
def micropost_params
     params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
```

it works.

But why....